# How to protect your API from abuse - DRF & React

Tags: reactjs, django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm really struggling to wrap my head around the concept of protecting ones API end point.

How do you do you protect it from abuse if it's exposed with React?

I understand if a user were to login then be issued them with a token etc. I get that. But let's say have a front end that does not require someone to be logged in?

They simply filling out a form with their details and it gets passed via you API then gets stored in the DB.

Whats stopping someone just abusing your API? They could just write a script and attack you end point with spammy data?

I just can't understand how this is protected?

Answer (score 0):

you can set **CORS headers**, **allowed hosts** and also **rate limiter** for protecting your APIs in Django.

**Allowed hosts:** A list of strings representing the host/domain names that Django site can serve. This is a security measure to prevent HTTP Host header attacks, which are possible even under many seemingly-safe web server configurations.

**CORS headers:** `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)` is an HTTP-header based mechanism that allows a server to indicate any origins (domain, scheme, or port) other than its own from which a browser should permit loading resources. It's used for working with browser clients.

**Rate limiting:** A rate limit is the maximum number of calls you want to allow in a particular time interval. For example each unauthenticated user can only do 100 requests per minute.

And also if you are deploying your app in a PaaS service then you can deploy your django app as an internal service and your react app as an external service. Then Django is not only usable inside the containers not outside them.

Comment: Thanks MojixCoder - As fas as Im aware Django allowed hosted is not API related? and CORS Headers as far as I understand is not to protect the server. But more the client? And this can be spoofed anyway. And rate limiting is great and will be applied but will still allow access. I'm aware of all of these. But its does not secure the API. Thoughts? Please correct me if I'm completely wrong here. I really need to understand this.

Comment: Yes allowed hosts are not related to apis, CORS only matters if your clients are browsers. But you can limit access with rate limiting.

Comment: I still don't understand how you secure an end point? The end point is not really secure with the methods you mentioned? As there are methods of bypassing. Whats stopping someone writing an abusive script that hits your API end point? Then in turn populates you DB with spam?

Comment: If you are looking for more advanced security issues check out this [link](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/). Read it and search how to be secure against them. But bypassing is not ad easy as u think

Comment: Thanks! I've tested this. And it's very easy to bypass and spam based on the methods you mentioned. I can simply add my own headers etc.  I'm clearly missing something.